# Even distribution of random points in 2D

Tags: random, plot, 2d, distribution, pseudocode

I'm trying to do a simple simple 'crowd' model and need distribute random points within a 2D area. This semi-pseudo code is my best attempt, but I can see big issues even before I run it, in that for dense crowds, the chances of a new point being too close could get very high very quickly, making it very inefficient and prone to fail unless the values are fine tuned. Probably issues with signed values too, but I'm leaving that out for simplicity.

```
int numPoints = 100;
int x[numPoints];
int y[numPoints];
int testX, testY;

tooCloseRadius = 20;
maxPointChecks = 100;
pointCheckCount = 0;

for (int newPoint = 0; newPoint < numPoints; newPoint++ ){

    //Keep checking random points until one is found with no other points in close proximity, or maxPointChecks reached.
    while (pointCheckCount < maxPointChecks){
        tooClose = false;
        // Make a new random point and check against all previous points
        testX = random(1000);
        testY = random(1000);
        for ( testPoint = 0; testPoint < newPoint; testPoint++ ){
            if  ( (isTooClose (x[testPoint] , y[testPoint], textX, testY, tooCloseRadius) ) {
            tooClose = true;
            break; // (exit for loop)
        }
        if (tooClose == false){
            // Yay found a point with some space!
            x[newPoint] = testX;
            y[newPoint] = testY;
            break; // (exit do loop)
        }
        //Too close to one of the points, start over.
        pointCheckCount++;
    }
    if (tooClose){
        // maxPointChecks reached without finding a point that has some space.
        // FAILURE DEPARTMENT
    } else {
        // SUCCESS
    }
}

// Simple Trig to check if a point lies within a circle.
(bool) isTooClose(centerX, centerY, testX, testY, testRadius){
    return (testX - centreX)^2 + (testY - centreY)^2)  < testRadius ^2
}
```

After googling the subject, I believe what I've done is called Rejection Sampling (?), and the Adaptive Rejection Sampling could be a better approach, but the math is far too complex.

Are there any elegant methods for achieving this that don't require a degree in statistics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the problem you are proposing the best way to generate random samples is to use Poisson Disk Sampling.

https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc

Now if you want to sample random points in a rectangle the simple way. Simply 
sample two values per point from 0 to the length of the largest dimension.

if the value representing the smaller dimension is larger than the dimension throw the pair away and try again.

Pseudo code:

```
while (need more points)
begin
   range = max (rect_width, rect_height);

   x = uniform_random(0,range);
   y = uniform_random(0,range);

   if (x > rect_width) or (y > rect_height)
    continue;
   else
     insert point(x,y) into point_list;
end
```

The reason you sample up to the larger of the two lengths, is to make the uniform selection criteria equivalent when the lengths are different.

For example assume one side is of length K and the other side is of length 10K. And assume the numeric type used has a resolution of 1/1000 of K, then for the shorter side, there are only 1000 possible values, whereas for the longer side there are 10000 possible values to choose from. A probability of 1/1000 is not the same as 1/10000. Simply put the coordinate value for the short side will have a 10x greater probability of occurring than those of the longer side - which means that the sampling is not truly uniform.

---

Pseudo code for the scenario where you want to ensure that the point generated is not closer than some distance to any already generated point:

```
while (need more points)
begin
   range = max (rect_width, rect_height)

   x = uniform_random(0,range);
   y = uniform_random(0,range);

   if (x > rect_width) or (y > rect_height)
    continue;

   new_point = point(x,y);

   too_close = false;

   for (p : all points)
   begin
     if (distance(p, new_point) < minimum_distance)
     begin
       too_close = true;
       break;
     end
   end

   if (too_close)
      continue;

   insert point(x,y) into point_list;
end
```

Comment: Can you explain uniform_random? Is this just a standard random function from 0->range?

Comment: @Kez yes. It will return a value uniform probability in the range [0,upper_bound] - where upper_bound is the length of the largest side.

Comment: ok, but why the use of range and not just x = uniform_random(0,rect_width); etc?

Comment: Also, Poisson Disc Sampling def seems right way. But your fast Pseudo code suffers from the same inefficiencies as mine, in fact its worse as it can be stuck in infinite loop without a timeout check.

Comment: In any case, I'm marking this correct for the Poisson Disc link as it is indeed a great solution, even if it requires substantially more code.

Answer (score 0):

While Poisson Disk solution is usually fine and dandy, I would like to point an alternative using quasi-random numbers. For quasi-random Sobol sequences there is a statement which says that there is minimum positive distance between points which amounts to 0.5*sqrt(d)/N, where `d` is dimension of the problem (2 in your case), and `N` is number of points sampled in hypercube. Paper from the man himself http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382.

Why I thought it should be Python? Sorry, my bad. For C-like languanges best to call GSL, function name is `gsl_qrng_sobol`. Example to use it at d=2 is linked [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Quasi_002drandom-number-generator-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks Severin Pappadeux, that is another great tip, although I'll have to get my head around that math. One problem with the Poisson Disc solution is that you always get 'tightly packed' points, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @Kez There are actually many problems with Poisson Disc. First, it is O(N) algorithm, which makes it slow for real simulations (like, million points). Second, it is unclear what the underlying distribution is, for, say, use with Monte Carlo integration. For U(0,1) you'll get usual monte carlo convergence as inverse sqrt(N). For quasi-random it is more close to inverse N. PD? Who knows... More links to look at: [Quasi-Random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence), you could look at the points uniformity. Another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling